# Django Перемещение объекта из одной дочерней модели в другую дочернюю модель

Tags: django, наследование, model

Есть модель - родитель, и две наследуемые от нее модели. У первой дочерней модели есть поле OneToOne к user, у второй поле ForeignKey к User. Допустим мы указали в другой (третьей) модели ключ к объекту из дочерней формы.
Каким образом можно переместить объект из одной дочерней модели в другую дочернюю модель, при этом, чтоб ссылка на этот объект осталась неизменной.
Пример:

```
class AllChar(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Никнейм')


class CharTwin(AllChar):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Владелец')


class CharMain(AllChar):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Владелец')


class History(models.Model):
    char = models.ForeignKey(AllChar, on_delete=??(NOTHING)??, verbose_name='Персонаж')
```

P.s: Раньше делал все в одной модели и обновлял поле main, чтоб определить к чему относится объект, но показалось что это костыльно, т.к. у user должно быть ток 1 CharMain и возможно несколько CharTwin

Comment: Эти модели будут в разных таблицах. Это не просто полиморфизм: из одной таблицы надо удалить, в другой создать.

Comment: Но чтоб ссылка с History осталась валидной - вопрос хороший. Мне в голову приходит только ручная правка таблиц. Может, кто подскажет идею получше

Comment: Либо `cursor.execute`